# Greater than and lesser than condition in xsl

Tags: xslt

I would like to have greater than and lesser than condition in xsl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </td>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="price &gt; '9' and price &lt; '10'">
                                    <td bgcolor="#B22222">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried

```
<xsl:when test="price &gt; 9 and price &lt; 10">.
```

But is not working.

Expected result: Display records which price is between 9 and 10.
Actual result : Nothing display

Comment: Can you share your xml?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>

I have cut down the options.

Comment: Please add also your xslt

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="price &gt; '9' and price &lt; '10'">
         <td bgcolor="#B22222">
         <xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Following Change:-

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the xsl namespace, and its working fine.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[price &gt; '9' and price &lt; '10']">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="#B22222">
                                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>Hide your heart</td>
            <td bgcolor="#B22222">Bonnie Tyler</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will return all records instead of return records where price is between 9 and 10

Comment: It return all records if I use the codes provided by you.
It work fine after I modify line below:
< --- from --->
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[price &gt; '9' and price &lt; '10']">
< --- to --->
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[price > '9' and price &lt; '10']">

I'm not sure why

Comment: I tested you using this online tester https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output

Comment: I try it at w3schools. Maybe something wrong there. I think is good for now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think are you want following:-

<xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="price &gt; 9 and price &lt; 10">
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

OutPut:-

```
<title>Hide your heart</title>
<artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>CBS Records</company>
<price>9.90</price>
<year>1988</year>
```

Comment: It will return all records instead of return records where price is between 9 and 10